# MySQL transaction takes unnecessary row locks with REPLACE

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, locking, rdbms

I'm experiencing strange row lock behavior when using replace and tables with both a unique key and primary key. I'm using read committed as my transaction isolation level.

```
CREATE TABLE x (x int, unique key (x), primary key (x));
INSERT INTO x VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4);

Transaction 1:
REPLACE INTO x VALUES (2);
```

For some reason this will take the lock for (1) and (3) but not for (0) and (4).

```
Transaction 2:
REPLACE INTO x VALUES (3);
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
REPLACE INTO x VALUES (4);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I tried looking for this bug in the mysql bug database but couldn't find anything. Can someone explain this weird behavior?